# Is the WinForms NotifyIcon class usable from non-UI-threads?

Tags: multithreading, winforms, notifyicon

Normally, UI controls must be used on the UI thread only. If you want to use a UI object from any other thread you usually have to invoke `Control.Invoke`. `NotifyIcon` does not have such a method.

What's the right way to do something with a `NotifyIcon` from a background thread?

*For example*, is the following legal? What's a legal alternative?

```
Task.Run(() => { notifyIcon.Visible = true; });
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718369/displaying-wpf-notifyicon-on-a-separate-thread) might help.

Comment: Maybe, pretty doubtful, the underlying Shell_NotifyIcon() function doesn't promise anything and shell functions are generally not thread-safe.  Doing it right [isn't that difficult](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant That answer helps. I could create the icon on an existing UI thread, capture the synchronization context and post to that context at any point in time later.